# How to pull related data for context in a template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have following models:

```
class Work_Music(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    tonality = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    tempo = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def is_opera(self):
        return hasattr(self, 'opera')

class Opera(models.Model):
    work = models.OneToOneField(Work_Music, verbose_name=_('work_music'), related_name='opera', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    librettist = models.ForeignKey(Person, verbose_name=_('librettist'), null=True, blank=True, related_name='person', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class OperaCast(models.Model):
    opera = models.ForeignKey(Opera, verbose_name=_('opera'), related_name='opera_cast', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

My view.py is:

```
class Work_MusicView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'composers/work_music/work.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        piece = Work_Music.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        piece_tree = Work_Music.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).get_family()

        opera = Opera.objects.get(work=self.kwargs['pk'])

    context.update({
        'piece': piece,
        'piece_tree': piece_tree,
        'opera': opera,
        'opera_cast': OperaCast.objects.filter(opera__work=self.kwargs['pk']).order_by('order'),
    })
    return context
```

For all pieces, opera or not, I am passing the Work_Music objects to template to display key, name, tonality and tempo of the piece. Not every piece is an opera.

If a piece of work is an opera, I'd like to display the librettist of the Opera as well as the opera cast in the context associated to the piece in a structured way. How do you do that?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to do. Can you be more specific about what you'd like to do in the template and what you've tried and why it hasn't worked?

Comment: @schillingt updated

Comment: What you have is pretty close to working. What problem(s) are you experiencing?

Comment: The 'opera metadata' is not connect to the 'piece'. So I would have to match 'piece' with 'opera' and 'opera_cast'. I need a more structure data to include in the context.

Comment: Using `piece.opera.opera_cast.all` in your template will work.